# Integrity error in django form saving

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Hey folks I have my model like :

```
class Rule(models.Model):
    Ruleinfo = models.CharField(max_length=5,null=False)
    Ispname  = models.CharField(max_length=5,null=False)
    priority = models.ForeignKey('Priority',related_name ="priority1")
    From  =    models.IPAddressField(null=True)
    To = models.IPAddressField(null=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %d' % (self.Ruleinfo, self.Ispname, self.priority,
                                      self.From, self.To)


class Priority(models.Model):  
    priority =  models.IntegerField(null = True)
    ispname = models.ForeignKey('Rule' ,related_name="ispname1")
    rule = models.ForeignKey('Rule',related_name="rule1")
```

and here is my forms

```
class RuleInfoForm(ModelForm):
     Ruleinfo = forms.CharField(max_length=5)   
     Ispname  = forms.CharField(max_length=5)
     priority = forms.IntegerField()
     From  =       forms.IPAddressField()   
     To    =       forms.IPAddressField()
     class Meta:
        model = Rule
        fields = ("Ruleinfo","Ispname","priority","From","To")
```

I am saving this form in my views as follow

```
def multiwanrule_info(request):
    data = {}
    try:
       form = RuleInfoForm(request.POST)
    except:
        pass
    if form.is_valid():
        rl_frm = form.save(commit=False)
        rl_frm.save()
    else:

        form = RuleInfoForm() 
        data['form'] = form    
    return render_to_response('networking.html',data)
```

But i am getting integrity error i.e

```
networking_rule.priority_id may not be NULL
```

why i am getting this error? Why it is not taking automatically like other tables

Comment: Does your data inside the form specifies a "Priority" object for submitted "Rule"? If not, and you don't want Django to force that, you should add "null=True" inside the `Rule.priority` field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem lies here:

```
 rl_frm = form.save(commit=False)
 rl_frm.save()
```

Since you don't have `null=True` in your `ForeignKey`, a valid foreign key is required; which you have not passed here.

So you should set the `ForeignKey` to `null=True`, then probably assign it:

```
 r1_frm.priority.pk = 1 # some primary key to a valid Priority object
 r1_frm.save()
```